# Assigning program output to a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a tool (written in C) that takes in output file parameter to which the tool writes some output string.

tool -o output-file-name

I would like to invoke the tool from a shell script and have the output string assigned to a variable.

I tried:

var=$(tool -o a.txt 1>/dev/null;cat a.txt && rm a.txt)

The above works, but I would like a more elegant solution.

P.S: I am far from a scripting guru.

Comment: You could try `tool -o /dev/stdout`

Comment: But a more elegant solution is to invoke `tool` with no arguments, and refactor `tool` so that it writes to stdout.  It is, after all, the standard place to write output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you. It worked for me. Not sure how I can mark you answer as accepted.

Comment: I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the tool without the option -o

```
tool
```

or like [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)   wrote with /dev/stdout as file

```
tool -o /dev/stdout
```

or in short form

```
tool -o -
```

Comment: This requires that `tool` recognize `-` as a special argument to mean stdin.  Many tools do this, but it's certainly not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming not possible to change to code to support output to stdout. Probably, because the code is sending additional information (logging) to stdout.

You can use IO redirection or process substitution to eliminate the need to save/recall the data from the file. The construct '>(cat)' argument tell bash the generate a pipe, between 'tool' and 'cat' (which will simply print the file).

```
# PREFERRED
# IO Redirection, using extra fd (#3).
var=$(./f.sh -o /dev/fd/3 3>&1 1>/dev/null)

# Use process substitution, use extra 'cat' process.
var=$(tool -o >(cat) >/dev/null)
```

1st solution more efficient (no extra cat running ...). 2nd solution is slightly more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on linux, you can use `tool -o /dev/stdout`